# preprocess view fields

Tags: views, theming, 6

I have a view with some fields wich I theme inside `views-view-fields--MYVIEW.tpl.php`. I use a `phptemplate_preprocess_views_view_unformatted__MYVIEW()` to preprocess some `$vars` before the template to have the template as *clean* as possible. But I don't know the right way of preprocessing the fields.

I can access the fieldcontent in the template via `$fields['MYFIELD']->content`. Inside the preprocess function I can't find this explicit `content` value. All I see is something called `last_render` but i'm not sure it's ok (the right way) to use/change this value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `debug()` to see the content of `$vars`. As far as I know, in views/themes/theme.inc there are many examples of preprocessing functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try `dsm($vars)`. It allows you to see the contents of `$vars` clearly. Note that you need the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module to do this.